# Is photon redshifted if observer starts moving away after photon is released

Tags: photons, redshift

**A.** A light source and an oberserver are stationary relative to each other.  The source emits a photon and the observer measures the wavelength.

**B.** A light source and an observer are stationary relative to each other.  The source emits a photon.  After the photon is emitted and while it is still in transit, the observer begins to move away from the source. The observer measures the wavelength while moving away from the source.

Is the photon wavelength redshifted in experiment B compared to experiment A?
If yes, how?  (Since the photon travels at speed c no matter the reference frame.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the light would be redshifted in experiment B. The measured Doppler shift depends on the velocity of the receiving instrument when the light is received relative to that of the emitter when the light was emitted.

The frequency and wavelength are both changed with respect to the values they would have in the frame of reference of the emitter, but their product, the speed of light, remains the same.

You can interpret this in terms of the classical Doppler effect modified by a time-dilation term. i.e. The relativistic Doppler effect is that
$$ \lambda_{\rm obs} = \lambda \sqrt\frac{c+v}{c-v} = \lambda\left(1 + \frac{v}{c}\right)\left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}$$
e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Relativistic_longitudinal_Doppler_effect

Comment: I see, thank you.  The redshift happens because of time dilation.

Comment: @user2577361 Partly. The shift is given by $\sqrt{(1 + v/c)/(1-v/c)}$ which is the product of a time dilation effect and the standard Doppler effect $(1+ v/c)/\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}$.

Comment: That's the part I don't fully get, the standard Doppler effect.  For sound waves, I understand why successive wave crests would be perceived as further apart when the source (or observer) is moving away.  Something is oscillating at a finite speed which creates the succesive sound wave crests. If we assume the air is stationary relative to the source, the sound waves will be travelling slower relative to the observer in scenario B vs. A.  Not so with light.  The speed is c no matter what and the "oscillation speed" of the light wave source has no effect on wavelength.

Comment: I still can't wrap my head around why the wavelength would get longer from the regular Doppler effect in this situation. (If the source was moving away at the time the photon was released, I could see it.)  In this situation, it is not.  Wavelengths are only being released when the the source and observer are not moving relative to each other, so I don't see why the wavelength would get longer then. The photon is moving at speed c relative to the observer no matter what, so the wavelength wouldn't get longer when it arrives either. I hope you can set me straight.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this situation (A vs B) not identical to when the source starts moving away from the observer after the photon is released?  How could the source effect the photon once it has left and is long gone and is far away?

Comment: You re-read but apparently misread. The fact that the observer was stationary when the light was emitted is irrelevant. What matters is that the the observer was moving when the light was received. The standard Doppler effect is symmetric to whether the emitter is moving or the receiver is moving. The moving observer sees a longer wavelength. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect and then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect @user2577361

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the direction of the photon emitted is towards the observer.

According to an approximation of Doppler Effect and Special Relativity, $λ$ = ($v/c$+1)$λ_0$, where $λ_0$ is the initial wavelength of the emitted photon and $λ$ is the resultant wavelength. $v$ is the velocity of the observer and $c$ is the speed of light.

In your case, the observer is receding from the source, so $v/c$ > 0 and so $λ$ > $λ_0$. This means redshift occurred in Experiment B.